# Echo command-line Questions

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, echo

So I'm new to linux and I'm try to learn the echo command

My first question is that I'm try to display all the files names (not content) in a certain directory of extention .txt without being that directory

I tried this 
`cd /directory/ | echo *.{txt}` but it doesnt work

Similarly what if I wanted to display all the files names (not content) starting with say, "the" followed by any 2 numbers
I have 
`echo the[0-9][0-9]*` but i dont think i got the syntax correct

and lastly, What if i want to display files with at least three characters but do not start with "the" ? ... <- I have no idea how to do this one

Any help and clarification would benefit me, Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "display all the files" do you mean, display a list of the filenames, or display the contents of the files?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by using proper pattern as argument to the `ls` command:

```
ls /directory/*.txt
```

As far as `echo` is concerned, it a command to just display its arguments.

Comment: This is exactly the same here. the `ls` command will just list the files already expanded by shell.

Comment: Well, not the same. ls will list one file per line. Whether this is what OP needs I don't know :)

Comment: yea i need echo cause i just wanna displayy the arguements

Comment: Another difference, BTW, is the directory in the command line. @codaddict's command will display `/directory/file.txt` whereas first `cd`-ing will display `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want either the list command (`ls`) or the `find` command, e.g.

```
ls /some/path *.txt


find /some/path *.txt
```

`ls` is relatively simple but limited.  `find` is somewhat more complicated, but has greater functionality and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /directory/ && echo *.txt
```

but that's not without being there. You can

```
(cd /directory/ ; echo *.txt )
```

if you want to go back after the command is executed.

```
echo the{0..9}{0..9}*
ls| grep -v ^the
```

And yes, if you want the contents of the files, you should use `cat` instead of `echo` and in the last case

```
cat $(ls|grep -v ^the)
```

(note, if your files have spaces, the last command will get more complex)

Comment: Sorry i dont care about the contents just the file or folder names, also I'm told this can all be done through echo, but if not i can learn up on cat ls and grep

Comment: Hmm im trying echo the{0..9}{0..9}* to work but its not, is it because it should be a dash instead of two dots?

Comment: No, it's 2 dots. Do you have files that match pattern?

Comment: So i have 2 files and 1 directory in the directory i am in; the23.txt the2.txt and a directory named the26 ... I type in the command and get no match i want it to display: the23.txt and the26

Comment: And you're in the directory where these files are? What's your shell and its version?

Comment: yes I am, and its the newest version im pretty sure.. basically seeing if i can display non-hidden files in the current directory starting with the and followed by two digits ... and i want it in the form `echo pattern`

Comment: okay i got it too work, but for your last answer I'm using `echo {^the}*` instead .. it works but it echo displays things with less than 3 characters too, how do make it show only files with at least 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show content of file you should use `cat`. `cat /directory/*.txt` and similarly for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
    ls /some/dir/*.txt
```

Question 2:

```
    ls /some/dir/the[0-9][0-9]*.txt
```

Question 3:

```
    ls /some/dir/*.txt | awk '{if(length($1) > 3 && substr($1,0,3) != "the"){print $1}}'
```